# File Dialog does not get refreshed unless CFrameWnd is hidden

Tags: c++, winforms, mfc, refresh, openfiledialog

I am updating some old software that does not work on Win7 or later. so, I am rebuilding some MFC libraries that are using latest win32 updates.

Now I have two issues:

1. *MessageBox appears behind the CFrameWnd so it can't be accessed sending the application to halt.*
2. *Open dialog box (whether is based on CFileDialog or IFileDilog) does not get refreshed when changing the file type.*

However, both problems are solved if the CFrameWnd is hidden. or, in case of MessageBox, you will not need to hide the window if you write: PostMessage(0x118); which in fact I don't know why.

There must be something I am missing Here.

I also Have another problem when using the OpenFileDialog class that inherits from the IFileDialog. is when closing this dialog without picking up a file, the application Crashes.

```
//--targetver.h
        #pragma once
        #include <sdkddkver.h>

//--stdafx.h:
        #ifndef CS_EXTRALEAN
        #define CS_EXTRALEAN
        #endif
        #pragma once
        #include "targetver.h"
        #include<afxwin.h>
        #include<afxext.h>
        #include<afxcmn.h>

//--stdafx.cpp
        #include "stdafx.h"

//--CMainWnd.h
        #pragma once

        class CMainWnd : public CFrameWnd
        {
        public:
            CMainWnd();
            ~CMainWnd();

            afx_msg void OnPaint();
            afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT, CPoint);

            DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
        };

//--CMainWnd.cpp
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include"CMainWnd.h"

    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainWnd, CFrameWnd)
        ON_WM_PAINT()
        ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()

    CMainWnd::CMainWnd()
        : CFrameWnd()
    {
        CString class_name = AfxRegisterWndClass(
            CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS,
            AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW),
            (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH),
            AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardIcon(IDI_ASTERISK));

        HRESULT hResult = this->Create(
            class_name,
            L"This is CMainWnd",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            this->rectDefault,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            0,
            NULL);
    }

    CMainWnd::~CMainWnd() { }

    void CMainWnd::OnPaint()
    { }

    void CMainWnd::OnLButtonDown(UINT, CPoint)
    {
        MessageBox(L"HELLO MFC", L"MFC", MB_OK);
    }

//--CAppWnd.h
#pragma once

class CAppWnd : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CAppWnd();
    ~CAppWnd();

    BOOL InitInstance();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

//--CAppWnd.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CAppWnd.h"
#include "CMainWnd.h"

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAppWnd, CWinApp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CAppWnd::CAppWnd()
    :CWinApp()
{ }

CAppWnd::~CAppWnd()
{ }

BOOL CAppWnd::InitInstance()
{
    this->m_pMainWnd = new CMainWnd;
    this->m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);

    return CWinApp::InitInstance();
}

CAppWnd The_App;
```

Comment: c++ is a long time ago but can you not give an owner to your MessageBox which would make it always appear on top of this owner ?

Comment: I tried didn't work. there must be something wrong with my code that I am not noticing.

Comment: than copy that code here not everyone is going to download your sources and look for it

Comment: it's better to download the code as it is easier to look at it from Visual studio rather than plenty of lines reading it from a web page. it is not a small function to pass.

Comment: No, it isn't. In fact, that alone is a reason to flag your question as *"off-topic"* (see [help/on-topic]).

Comment: Anyway, to give you a few hints (again). If a message box appears behind a window, then that message box doesn't properly have its owner set. It could either be, that the owner designates the wrong window, or the designated owner window is owned by another thread. Either case would exhibit the error mode you describe.

Comment: Never had any problem using these functions. If you set the owner HWND in the MessageBox() call, it behaves at exactly the desired way: blocks user input in the owner window and displays a "modal" message-box on top of it. Don't know what happens if the call to MessageBox() takes place in the context of a thread other than the one that owns the parent window though. If a proper owner HWND is not available (eg in the case of a DLL), try setting the MB_TASKMODAL flag.

Comment: The Spy tool can show what window is owner of the _MessageBox_.

Comment: You have some major errors that's why `MessageBox` is not showing properly. Since you don't want to show the relevant source code, I suggest you use Visual Studio to create a new minimal MFC project, compare it with your own project to see where things go wrong. You probably want to create it as MFC standard (with no Doc/View support, no tabs, no ribbon, no toolbar...)

Comment: HI Guys. After many efforts, I learned how to add code to the question. so I deleted the link and replaced it with the code. Now, lets get down to business and someone can answer why the message box appears behind the CFrameWnd.

Comment: That's a much better MCVE. The previous code you uploaded was over 60 mega bytes of stuff.

Comment: Thanks Barmak. it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a simple problem. You override `OnPaint` but didn't call the default procedure. `OnPaint` handles to `WM_PAINT` message, it doesn't forgive this error.

```
void CMainWnd::OnPaint()
{ 
    CFrameWnd::OnPaint(); //<= this was missing

    //custom paint...
    //CClientDC dc(this);
    //dc.TextOut(0, 0, L"test");
    //dc is automatically released...
}
```

Or you can use `CPaintDC` which is a wrapper for `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` API

```
void CMainWnd::OnPaint()
{ 
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    //custom paint...
    //dc.TextOut(0, 0, L"test");
    //dc is automatically released...
}
```

If you don't do any painting in this frame window then remove the whole `CMainWnd::OnPaint()` function and the correspoonding `ON_WM_PAINT` message.

Above change should fix your error. I would rewrite the rest of the code so it calls the default override first. Example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"

class CMainWnd : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    CMainWnd();
    ~CMainWnd();
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT, CPoint);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainWnd, CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CMainWnd::CMainWnd() : CFrameWnd() {}
CMainWnd::~CMainWnd() {}

void CMainWnd::OnPaint()
{ 
    CFrameWnd::OnPaint();
}

void CMainWnd::OnLButtonDown(UINT f, CPoint pt)
{
    CFrameWnd::OnLButtonDown(f, pt);
    CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, 0, 0, 0, 
        L"All files|*.*|" 
        L"Text files|*.txt;*.txt||" , this);
    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
        MessageBox(dlg.GetPathName(), L"MFC", MB_OK);
}

class CAppWnd : public CWinApp
{
public:
    BOOL InitInstance();
};

BOOL CAppWnd::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();
    CMainWnd *frame = new CMainWnd;
    CString class_name = AfxRegisterWndClass(
        CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS,
        AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW),
        (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH),
        AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardIcon(IDI_ASTERISK));

    frame->Create(class_name, L"This is CMainWnd", 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CFrameWnd::rectDefault, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);
    frame->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
    m_pMainWnd = frame;
    return TRUE;
}

CAppWnd The_App;
```

Note that you can call up static members directly, for example `CFrameWnd::rectDefault`, it doesn't cause an error either way but it makes the code more clear.